# detect client process termination from EXE COM Server

Tags: windows, com

I'm writing an EXE COM Server that exposes a class that lock a system resource.
In normal execution the client release the resource (the COM executable shutsdown a couple of seconds later.
In abnormal execution, the client app crashes, leaving the com sever with an instance having a positive reference count. The COM executable runs for ~12 minutes until termination. This means that the system resource is locked during this time.

Is there a way to detect client termination instantaneously, as in socket IPC or driver protocol? if not it would seem that COM is inferior to other IPC mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question a couple of years ago. I found the answer here: [How To Turn Off the COM Garbage Collection Mechanism](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171414). In short: no, there is no way to detect client termination instantaneously. Excerpts:

> When a COM client terminates normally,
>   it releases all references to its
>   server object. When a client
>   terminates abnormally however, there
>   might be outstanding references to the
>   server object. Without a garbage
>   collection mechanism, the server code
>   has no way of knowing when to reclaim
>   the resources allocated for the COM
>   object, which can then cause a
>   resource leak. To address this
>   problem, COM implements an automatic
>   garbage collection mechanism in which
>   the COM resolver process (RPCSS) on
>   the client machine pings the server
>   machine on behalf of the client
>   process.
>
> Alternatives to using COM's GC
>   protocol (for example, using periodic
>   application-level "pings"--method
>   calls that inform the object that
>   clients are still alive, or using an
>   underlying transport mechanism such as
>   TCP keepalives) are demonstrably much
>   less efficient. Therefore, DCOM's
>   default GC mechanism should be used
>   for any objects that must be shut down
>   when their clients disappear or
>   otherwise misbehave if those objects
>   would effectively become memory leaks
>   on the server.
>
> The resolver on the server machine
>   keeps track of the pings for each
>   server object. The ping period is 2
>   minutes and, currently, it is non-
>   configurable. When the resolver on the
>   server machine detects that an object
>   has not been pinged for 6 minutes, it
>   assumes that all clients of the object
>   have terminated or otherwise are no
>   longer using the object. The resolver
>   will then release all external
>   references to the object. It does this
>   by simply having the object's stub
>   manager (the COM runtime code that
>   delivers calls to each object) call
>   ::Release() on the object's IUnknown
>   interface. At this point, the object's
>   reference count will be zero so far as
>   the COM runtime is concerned. (There
>   may still be references held by local
>   (same-apartment) clients, so the
>   object's internal reference count may
>   not necessarily go to zero at this
>   point.) The object may then shut
>   itself down.
>
> NOTE: Garbage collection applies to
>   all servers regardless of whether
>   their clients are local or remote, or
>   a combination of local and remote. The
>   underlying pinging mechanism is
>   different in the local case as no
>   network packets are generated, but for
>   all practical purposes, the behavior
>   is the same.